# Create database using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want create database with codeigniter 3 but show errors

My code :

```
class Starter extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->dbforge();

                echo 'Hello World!';
        }
}
```

show error :
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sky/system/database/drivers//_forge.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sky/system/core/Loader.php on line 454
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Compile Error

Message: require_once(): Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sky/system/database/drivers//_forge.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php')

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 454

Backtrace:

I want to create a new database for each new customer